# Determining the type of output data of Hadoop MapReduce at runtime not possible?

Tags: hadoop, serialization, mapreduce, type-erasure, generics

Hadoop Framework needs to know the output data types from the Mapper and Reducer to create instances of those types at runtime to deserialize values between the Mapper and Reducer as well as during serializing instances from the Reducer to the output files. Therfore we have to tell Hadoop framework about the output data in job object like

```
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

It is not possible to infer the types at runtime from the class definitions of the Mapper and Reducer since Java Generics uses Type Erasure.
```

Say this is a mapper class

```
public static class SelectClauseMapper
    extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if(!AirlineDataUtils.isHeader(value)){
            StringBuilder output = AirlineDataUtils.mergeStringArray(
                AirlineDataUtils.getSelectResultsPerRow(value),
                ",");
                context.write(NullWritable.get(),new Text(output.toString()));
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain in the context of the above example that why it is not possible to determine the output types at runtime?